# Not able to set the data for sorting requirement

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I am trying to sort my datas by extending the `Ember` object. But getting error as : `TypeError: dataFilter.set is not a function` any one please correct me or show me the correct way to sort?

I am trying to keep the separate object for sorting or filter purposes.

here is my code :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

let dataFilter = Ember.Object.extend({
    cardList:null,
    sortByAmountSpent:Ember.computed.sort('name', 'cardList'),
    sortByDateOfPurchase:Ember.computed.sort('age', 'cardList')
})

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    combineArray:Ember.computed(function(){
        return [
                {"name":"name1","age":"age1"},
                {"name":"name2","age":"age2"},
                {"name":"name0","age":"age3"}
            ];
    }),
    actions:{
        sortByDateOfPurchase:function(){
            dataFilter.set('cardList', this.get('combineArray') );
        },
        sortByAmountSpent:function(){
            dataFilter.set('cardList', this.get('combineArray') );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, you have defined a `class` named `dataFilter` via extending `Ember.Object`; however you did not create any instance from it. Running the code `dataFilter.set('cardList', this.get('combineArray') );` naturally throws an error indicating `dataFilter.set is not a function`. `dataFilter` is not an instance. If you declare `dataFilter` as

```
let dataFilter = Ember.Object.extend({
    cardList:null,
    sortByAmountSpent:Ember.computed.sort('name', 'cardList'),
    sortByDateOfPurchase:Ember.computed.sort('age', 'cardList')
}).create();
```

then those lines will not be throwing errors; because `dataFilter` will be an instance of the class defined and `set` is naturally defined in an instance of a class extending `Ember.Object`.

Comment: works fine. thanks. additionally i created a `component` and got the js like this. `import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/cs2i-transation-multiselect-new';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout
});
` but nothing loads in to page. any idea?

Comment: need more detail I guess. can you share more code with a new question if possible?

Comment: can you look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882534/ember-component-what-is-layout-and-how-to-write-the-functions