# Ember component what is layout and how to write the functions?

Tags: ember.js

I created a component, it gives the output as :

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/sample-work';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout
});
```

When i try to add some init method like :

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/sample-work';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout,
  init(){
    alert.log('hi');
  }
});
```

My component not at all called. what is the issue here? what is the correct way to handle the component here?

Comment: are you developing and addon? how did you create the component? did you use `ember-cli`?

Comment: did you ever put the component within `application.hbs` or `index.hbs` via {{sample-work}} for instance.

Comment: Yes I use CLI through command prompt

Comment: Yes I put. I guess I Am getting something connected to name issue

Comment: Is there any name restriction? I try this : `ember g component cs2i-transation-multiselect-new` which is not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do not need the `layout` within `js` file; because `ember` is an opinionated framework and it usually puts the component's `js` and `hbs` files to places where it can match them automatically by default: `js` is placed under  `components` and `hbs` file is placed under `templates\components`.

In case; you put the template file to a place where it is not directly available to `js` file you need to import the layout. Take a look at the [simple twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5a0eca590b838a4bfb708d0d2b431655?openFiles=components.my-component2.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) I have prepared for you. In this twiddle; `my-component2`'s template file needs to be imported as `layout` field within corresponding `js` file.

Comment: In add-ons you need the layout

Comment: @Lux true. I wrote it as comment and asked it!

Answer (score 1):

You should always call `this._super(...arguments)` inside your init function